# SSIS - Import Excel file and stop at first empty row

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, ssis

I am importing an Excel table into my SSIS-Package. 
What I know:

- I know at which row the data in the Excel file starts
- I know how many columns I need
- I know that after the last import row there comes an empty row

So the amount of rows vary. How can I tell SSIS to import the data until the first empty row. My idea is to write a script in `C#` and to store the row ID of the empty row in a variable. With that variable I could specify the import matrix of my excel file.

Actually I do not have any experiences in `C#`. Can anyone help me with that? Or does anyone have a better idea?
Thank you in advance!!

[image]

Comment: A CSV doesn't have text before or after the data. Unfortunately, what customers provide as "CSV files" is usually the screenshot of a report or other *plain text* file. SSIS can handle such dirty files, to an extent. You can skip rows at the start and specify that errors are ignored. This will cause the data source to skip starting text and footers.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, thanks for your answer. Actually I do not have a CSV file. I get this excel file from a customer and don't want to manually process the file by myself.

Comment: If that doesn't work, you probably need to cleanup the files and convert them to actual CSVs. This doesn't require code. You could use powershell to read the lines of each file, filter out those you don't want and write out those you do. Eg, skip the first 10 lines with `Select -Skip 10` or the last 10 with `Select -SkipLast 10`.

Comment: ok thanks, good idea. Yet I will try to import them with excel. If that will not work I will try your approach.

Comment: You can query data in Excel as if it were a table, eg `SELECT * FROM [Emp1$A10:E50]` will select the data in the Range between A10 and E50. Check [this FAQ](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/ssis/importing-excel-data-into-sql-server-via-ssis-questions-you-were-too-shy-to-ask/)

Comment: Yes right I know that. But I don't know (taking your example) whether E50 is my last row.

Comment: Excel itself will stop if there are no other rows. *I think* it stops at the first empty row as well. Excel also allows you to *name* ranges and treat them as tables, and query eg: `SELECT * From [Sheet1$MyData]`

Comment: Finally, as [this shows](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/ssis/importing-excel-data-into-sql-server-via-ssis-questions-you-were-too-shy-to-ask/#eighth) you can add a NULL check for certain fields in the query to ensure you don't read data from empty lines

Comment: Have a Look at my screenshot above. There are also some comments in that excel worksheet so I can not take the whole sheet. At the moment row 167 is the last row. Until this row Id like to import all data

Comment: I suggest you try it. It might actually stop at the correct row, as already mentioned

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work with an Where Clause. I tried the following:
`Select * FROM [Kursliste Intranet$A3:H167] WHERE H IS NOT NULL`
I am getting this error: 
> No value given for one or more required parameters. (Microsoft JET Database Engine)

Comment: What happens if you use the same query without a WHERE clause?